# Unable To Connect The Specified MySQL Hosts

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have an application that requires my users to connect to an online MySQL database through "remote access" from ANY IP address (the IP address from their own internet network) so that it confirms they are in the database prior to accessing the software.

I have tried to run command lines in my Linux terminal to allow ALL users to connect remotely from any ip address using the following command:

```
GRANT ALL ON database_name.* TO root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'user_password';
```

I have configured my MySQL database server configuration file to enable proper remote connection (I believe).

My "MySQL database server configuration file" located in /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf looks like the following below:

```
#
    # The MySQL database server configuration file.
    #
    # You can copy this to one of:
    # - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
    # - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
    # 
    # One can use all long options that the program supports.
    # Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
    # --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
    #
    # For explanations see
    # http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

    # This will be passed to all mysql clients
    # It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
    # escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
    # Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.

    # Here is entries for some specific programs
    # The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

    [mysqld_safe]
    socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
    nice        = 0

    [mysqld]
    #
    # * Basic Settings
    #
    user        = mysql
    pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
    socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
    port        = 3306
    basedir     = /usr
    datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
    tmpdir      = /tmp
    lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
    skip-external-locking
    #
    # Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
    # localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
    bind-address        = 0.0.0.0
    #require_secure_transport = on
    #
    # * Fine Tuning
    #
    key_buffer_size     = 16M
    max_allowed_packet  = 16M
    thread_stack        = 192K
    thread_cache_size       = 8
    # This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
    # the first time they are touched
    myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP
    #max_connections        = 100
    #table_open_cache       = 64
    #thread_concurrency     = 10
    #
    # * Query Cache Configuration
    #
    query_cache_limit   = 1M
    query_cache_size        = 16M
    #
    # * Logging and Replication
    #
    # Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
    # Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
    # As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
    #general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
    #general_log             = 1
    #
    # Error log - should be very few entries.
    #
    log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
    #
    # Here you can see queries with especially long duration
    #slow_query_log     = 1
    #slow_query_log_file    = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
    #long_query_time = 2
    #log-queries-not-using-indexes
    #
    # The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
    # note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
    #       other settings you may need to change.
    #server-id      = 1
    #log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
    expire_logs_days    = 10
    max_binlog_size   = 100M
    #binlog_do_db       = include_database_name
    #binlog_ignore_db   = include_database_name
    #
    # * InnoDB
    #
    # InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
    # Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
    #
    # * Security Features
    #
    # Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
    # chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
    #
    # For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
    #
    # ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
    # ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
    # ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem
```

I have also tried to unblock the FireWall to enable tcp connection using the following command line:

```
sudo ufw allow 3306/tcp
```

My connection string from my desktop application looks like this:

```
MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=MyServerIPaddress;Port=3306;database=MyDatabaseName;Uid=root;Pwd=MyPassword;Connect Timeout=30;SslMode=none;"
```

My users still get the "*Unable to connect to any of the specified mysql hosts.*" error message.
Any support is appreciated.

Comment: Can you confirm TCP port 3306 is open and accessible from public network?

Use `netcat` for example: `nc -v [YOUR IP] 3306` should return `Connection to [YOUR IP] port 3306 [tcp/mysql] succeeded!`

After you confirm the port is open, the server should receive the incoming connections. If you're still unable to connect, post the mysql server log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a giant point of an API; to expose some set of predefined functionality in a controlled manner without having to expose the soft underbelly of a site or system by dismantling the security.

https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/263768-setting-up-a-php-web-service-to-be-consumed-by-vbnet/